# Multiple entry Schengen tourist Visa requirements from India

Tags: visas, schengen, spain

I am an Indian national who will be moving to UK on Work visa (Tier 2) this month end. I plan to visit my fiancee who is studying in University in Barcelona during my off weekends but BLS website for Spain visa shows information only for Single-entry visa nor there's any information regarding that on Spanish embassy website.

As per my Knowledge, one can not apply for multiple entry Schengen visa from UK till they have at least 3 months bank statement (aka can apply for that only after 3 months of work in UK)

Does Spain issue schengen tourist visa (multiple entry) from India?

Answer (score 2):

- To get a multiple-entry Schengen visa, you need a history of single-entry visas (without overstay or similar incidents) and a premise to justify repeat visits. Probably your first couple of visas will be single-entry visa with a very narrow period of validity.
- Usually you should apply from your *place of residence*. This does not require employment, but of course employment helps to document a settled lifestyle and ties to your place of residence.
- Bank statements are one part of documenting those ties. [This answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab) talks about the UK, but the principle is the same.
- Depending on the immigration status of your fiancee and the permanence of your relationship, you might be able to get a family visa.

Most likely, you will have to apply for several single-entry visa before a multiple-entry visa is considered. And you probably won't be able to get any visa in the time where you are still resident in India.

Comment: I couldn't understand what did you mean by "And you probably won't be able to get any visa in the time where you are still resident in India."

Comment: As I understand it, your place of residence will change this month when you move to the UK. As a resident of the UK, you have to apply in London or Manchester. As a resident of India, you have to apply in one of the centres in India. I considered it unlikely that an application in India would have been processed before your move.